# What's the plural of "panicky"?

Tags: plural-forms

I read that panicky refers to a person who panics. What's the plural of that?

Comment: Adjectives don't have plurals.....

Comment: Could you explain how you want to use this in a sentence?  In English we don't have to make adjectives plural to match a plural noun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase **the panicky** would mean "everyone who is panicky" or "those who are panicky".

You could have a magazine article with this title:

> Ten ways to make things worse for the panicky

or

> The panicky: how to get them going

That is a  collective reference.

Answer (score 3):

A person who panics can be said to be a panicky person.

panicky is an adjective. Adjectives in English are invariable.

Comment: And people who panic are also **panicky** people.  As you say, invariable.

Comment: Adjectives don't inflect for number like nouns do, but they aren't invariant.  Many adjectives have comparative and superlative inflections.

Comment: Merriam Webster: : inflection: the change of form that words undergo to mark such distinctions as those of case, gender, number, tense, person, mood, or voice. They do not change their form for gender and number. Comparatives are a separate grammatical category.

Comment: This is non-controversial, and the definition you supplied certainly does not contradict my comment; it says "such as", and grade is expressed lexically, inflectionally, and analytically in English.  Please see any competently written book on grammar, for example *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk et al 1985) p.402, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum 2002) p.533, the *Longman Grammar of Spoken and Written English* (Biber et al 1999) p.522, and see also *A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics, 6th ed.* (Crystal 2008) p.12.

Comment: @snailboat You can quote all the books you please. I stand by my comment. Comparatives are a separate issue.

Comment: That’s fine.  The downvote and the comment are to prevent future users from being misled.  You’re under no obligation to fix your post.

Comment: Here's why: comparatives in English are regular and irregular. So, it is a mistake to include comparatives here as that would have to include:  Good, better, best or bad, worse, worst which, in fact, are ***actually different words*** and are also ***invariable*** as words. Misleading is as misleading does....

Answer (score 0):

In English, adjectives don't pluralize, but sometimes we use an adjective as if it were a noun to talk about a group of things that have that quality -- which is confusing, I know.

For example, "green" is a noun describing a color, but "greens" is often used as a generic term for "green vegetables", "a group of green fields", or some other group or class of thing that are all green.  So if a mother tells her child, "You need to eat your **greens**", it looks like a plural adjective, but really isn't.

Back to your original question, I think probably your definition is slightly wrong. "Panicky" means "being prone to panic", but not a person who does that. So you could have panicky people or panicky cows, but you wouldn't use the word alone to refer to a person with that quality.

The exception is the the one Tromano gave -- sometimes we use "the" with an adjective to refer collectively to everyone or everything that has that quality.  "A nurse helps **the sick**" means "all people who are sick".  So you could say something like, "The captain's powerful voice and stoic presence helped to calm **the panicky** while the lifeboats were being prepared."  In this case it's short for "the people who were panicky".